# Plupload messing up jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, plupload

I am using the image uploader Plupload and it is causing errors with the other jquery I have on my page. I have figured out exactly what part is doing it:

```
function $(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id); 
}
```

If I take this out the image uploader no longer works but the jquery does. It is a lot of code to post here, does anyone have another way to call this function so that it works with jquery? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use jQuery like this:

```
jQuery(function($){
  //Your jQuery code here
  // Use $ alias worry-free of conflicts
  alert('You are using jQuery ' + $().jquery );
});
```

or

```
(function($){
  //Your jQuery code here
})(jQuery);
```

or

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
```

or

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
// Do something with jQuery
j("div p").hide();
// Do something with another library's $()
$("content").style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: You're welcome, I personally prefer to use the second or the forth example.